# How to add remove-ads in-app purchases in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I hope you can help me with this. I need to add a remove ads in-app purchase in a flutter app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends how did you add your ads in your app but easiest way you can use a flag/bool value like "purchased" or something and if someone purchased your app make that flag is true and put a if else condition to your code to where you show ads like `purchased ? Row() : YOUR ADS`

Comment: Where to store that purchased bool value?

Comment: Depends on you. If you use a login option you can save with them. If you don't you can use sharedpreferences but it will cause a problem if user change phone or clear data of app. So you want to check purchase situation of your app, there is some libraries for that such as:https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase